# Terminal/iTerm Autocomplete "greyed" functionality?

Tags: terminal, iterm, auto-complete

Not too sure how to describe this... but I saw this on a person's computer a cafe today and didn't get a chance to ask him what plugin/application he was using --

I think it best to illustrate with an example:

Say there's a directory with three folders, 'kitty', 'doggie', and 'frog'.

Typing `cd f` would make the letters `rog` appear after the 'f', but `rog` would be in a lighter color of text (a greyed color) -- it was a sort of "visible autocomplete", not sure what else to call it. Anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a feature of [the `fish` shell](http://fishshell.com) (Friendly Interactive Shell).

[image: Image of feature]

`fish`'s scripting syntax is also quite a bit different from `bash` and `zsh`'s. If you use `zsh`, you can also try the `zsh-autosuggestions` plugin [on Github](https://github.com/tarruda/zsh-autosuggestions).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there's anything like this for `bash`?

Comment: [I don't think so](http://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/1z7cne/does_bash_have_an_autosuggest_like_fish_screenshot/) unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a plugin for oh-my-zsh:
https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions. It explicitly aims at Fish-like functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like like iTerm2 feature.

See [this for complete list of Features](http://iterm2.com/features.html) including the Autocomplete and Highlighting.